# Linux - Checking if user has entered numbers and letters

Tags: linux, shell-script

The script I am trying to create should ask the user to enter a password. This password will then be checked if it contains a capital, characters and numbers

This is all I have so far before I got lost and started googling for ways of doing this

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Please enter a password containing numbers and letters"
read password

if [[password =~ [0-9] ]]
then 
    echo "Successful"
else
    echo "Fail"
fi
```

Comment: Is your intent for it to require a number, uppercase, lowercase, and special character?

Comment: @Jesse_b yes this is what I intend

Answer (score 2):

Some issues with your code:

1. You need a space between `[[` and `password`
2. `password` will be a variable and therefore needs to be written as `$password` to expand
3. You are using the `#!/bin/sh` hashbang and therefore the bash extended test (`[[`) may not be available
4. You are only checking if the password contains numbers

---

I think a function would be best for checking if the password meets your requirements and have come up with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

chk_pass () {
    local pass=$1
    # Check if password contains uppercase
    printf '%s' "$pass" | grep -q '[A-Z]' || return 1
    # Check if password contains lowercase
    printf '%s' "$pass" | grep -q '[a-z]' || return 1
    # Check if password contains numbers
    printf '%s' "$pass" | grep -q '[0-9]' || return 1
    # Check if password contains special characters
    printf '%s' "$pass" | grep -q '[^a-zA-Z0-9 \t]' || return 1
    return 0
}

printf '%s\n' 'Please enter a password containing at least one number, one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, and one special character: '
read -rs 
if chk_pass "$REPLY"; then
    printf '%s\n' 'Success'
else
    printf '%s\n' 'Error: Password must contain one number, one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, and one special character!' >&2
fi
```

Notes:

The last `grep` in the function actually only checks that the password contains characters *other than* alphanumeric or whitespace.
The `-r` option for read will preserve backslash characters
The `-s` option for read will hide user input (useful for password input)